# Zenity and bash

Tags: bash, zenity

I have a broblem with bash script.
I want to go back to menu but have an error from terminal "unexpected end of file"

```
#!/bin/bash 
users=$(awk -F'[/:]' '{if ($3 >= 1000 && $3 != 65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd)
menu(){
ans=$(zenity  --list  --text "Izvēlies funkciju" --radiolist  --column "Pick" --column "" TRUE "Lietotāju saraksts" False "Pievienot jaunu lietotāju" FALSE "Dzēst lietotāju" FALSE "Aktivizēt lietotāju" FALSE "Deaktivizēt lietotāju");
}
menu

if [ "$ans" = "Lietotāju saraksts" ]; then

 zenity --info --text=$users else

    if [ $? == '0' ]; then
menu

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
zenity --info --text=$users else
```

sends `else` as a parameter to zenity. You need a semicolon or newline before `else`.

You'll need another `fi` to close the outer `if`, too.